# How to find replacement cabinet hinge screws with large diameter, flat tip and coarse thread

Tags: screws, woodworking, cabinets, mdf

I'm upgrading some hinges on frameless MDF cabinets and need to source additional screws that will ideally match the existing threaded holes. The screws securing these hinges are unique to me, but must adhere to some sort of standard. They are a much larger diameter than the wood screws that ship with most cabinet hinges (~1/4" major diameter) and have the coarse thread of a wood screw but the flat tip of a machine screw. Interesting enough, they also appear to be pozidriv. That part may be useful for identification, but not critical for replacement.

[image: what kind of screw is this?]

I'm assuming that this is some kind of "confirmat" screw that's specifically designed to work in shallow particleboard, but I can't find equivalents. The local store doesn't stock anything, and a variety of online searches have been unsuccessful.

**What naming standard do these screws adhere to, and where are they found?**

I'd like to source replacements that would allow me to reuse the existing holes, and ideally find the same screw with a slightly longer shaft to secure replacement hinges with thicker mounting flanges. It's clear that these screws are extremely solid in MDF an I'd like to stick to this standard if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Because the screws are going into MDF there's a likelihood that you won't get much in the way of "existing threads" to fasten into. Often repeated activity can cause any threads in MDF to loosen up or crumble when trying to tighten the screws, etc.

If this is the case, or if you can't find the right screws, you have the option of drilling out the screw holes and gluing in lengths of hardwood dowels to fill the holes. Once the hardwood plugs are glued in place you can use regular wood screws to attach the hinges.

There are also plastic "plugs" specifically made for this which go into an enlarged hole and receive a screw that forces the plug to expand and hold tightly in the hole.

[image: plastic plugs for stripped screw holes, via Amazon]

I think the glue/dowels would provide a stronger, more long-lasting solution, but the plastic plugs might be "highly adequate" and easier/faster to install. It could be argued that either method will provide a stronger interface than screws in bare MDF though.

Answer (score 1):

Those look like what I know as Conformat screws, made specifically for MDF and similar materials. Some hardware stores may have them; if you bring in the screw you're trying to match you should be able to find the length and head size you need.

Home centers may have them but in boxes of 50 rather than as single screws.

Woodworking stores may have them in packages of 10 or so. There too,if you bring in the screw they can probably help you match it.

If you can get accurate enough measurements you could try searching for Conformat screws online....

Comment: My local big box store has a section of specialty screws in pull out drawers.  Those kind of fasteners can be found there, usually in packages of one or five.

Comment: @keshalm, yes, I think "confirmat" (sp?) was the keyword that got me closest to useful results online, but everything seemed to be for cabinet building (e.g. long screws for butt joints). The challenge may just be finding a shorter length.